# Pass a QVariantMap to Javascript (QtWebkit)

Tags: qt4.7, qwebkit

I have a `QVariantMap`, which I would like to pass to Javascript via a signal.

c++:

```
signals:
    void mysignal( QVariantMap map );


QVariantMap map;
map.insert( "id", 54 );
emit mysignal( map );
```

---

js:

```
mybinding.mysignal.connect( this, function( map ) {
    alert( "Map: " + map );  
} );
```

Now the alert  just displays `Map:`.
Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

```
mybinding.mysignal.connect( this, function( map ) {
    alert( "Map: " + map );  
} );
```

You map is a object (QVariantMap). so if you wan to access the values you should use

```
mybinding.mysignal.connect( this, function( map ) {
    alert( "Map_ID: " + map.id );  
} );
```

This give you an alert message indicating 54

Answer (score 0):

Found that passing via `QVariant` works:

c++:

```
signals:
    void mysignal( QVariant map );



QVariantMap map;
map.insert( "id", 54 );
emit mysignal( QVariant::fromValue(map) );
```

Why the binding does work only this way? I have no idea.